# How to let a function check multiple things

Tags: python-2.7

I'm making a simple program that converts imperial units to metric units. Like kW to hp and mph to kph. I want to let python check the first variable for multiple keywords. So that if the first keywords aren't in the variable, it checks the next line of keywords

I've tried lists and played around with the conditions

```
def choice():
    choice = raw_input("What do you want to convert?")
    splitted = choice.split()
    value = float(splitted[0])
    if 'kw' or 'kW' in choice:
        kwpk(value)
    elif 'mph' in choice:
        miletokm(value)
```

With this method it always returns the kwpk(value). Even if the input doesn't have the keywords in it. I'm kinda ashamed that i need to ask this, but it's bothering me for like 2 days now even though it's a very simple application.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a tiny error in your condition> When you're adding in two conditions seperated by a boolean operator, you'll have to mention them seperately. 
Instead of:

```
if 'kw` or 'kW' in choice:
```

Try:

```
if 'kw' in choice or 'kW' in choice:
```

Even better, you can avoid the two cases and just use `lower()` to normalize the string.

```
def choice():
    choice = raw_input("What do you want to convert?")
    splitted = choice.split()
    value = float(splitted[0])
    if 'kw' in choice.lower():
        kwpk(value)
    elif 'mph' in choice:
        miletokm(value)
```

Comment: No worries @kursad333. Happy it helped. :)